# how to handle the saving failure after raft committed

Tags: etcd, raft

when using raft, after log entries commited, we should write the data which is proposed by a node into our storage. what if one of node write failed. let's say the disk got bad. should the failure node terminate itself?

```
the proces like the following.
1. node A propose with data "abc"
2. raft log committed
3. A write data "abc" to file ok.
   B write data "abc" to file ok.
   C write data "abc" failed.
what should we do now ? since C won't have data "abc"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that those changes are already persisted in the Raft log. Raft doesn't even guarantee that once a change is committed x (e.g. write the change to another file) will happen within any time frame. So

> C won't have data "abc"

This is not accurate. The data has been persisted in the Raft log, it just hasn't been written to some other file after it was committed. What you're describing here is the behavior of a persistent state machine, wherein data is persisted in some separate store *after* it's been committed in the Raft log. But don't forget that committing data in the Raft log is tantamount to persisting it.

Persistent state machines have requirements beyond just the basic Raft protocol, and more on them can be found in the [raft dissertation](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/~ongaro/thesis.pdf). Typically, in a persistent state machine you need to persist the `lastApplied` index in addition to `term` and `votedFor`. As entries are committed and applied to the persistent state machine (e.g. written to the data file on each node), the `lastApplied` index is persisted. Entries are not removed from the Raft log until they've been successfully applied. This is how you ensure your data `"abc"` is not lost even if it can't be written to a file on node `C`.